# Problems reading a system file with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to execute a shell script in which I am trying to open the file /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status through awk. But, the script fails to execute saying that the file cannot be read. Even executing the script with sudo does not work. Below is the script. I am on Kubuntu 13.10. I searched a lot, but couldn't find a solution. Thanks for the help!

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '{
echo $0
}' | /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status
```

Comment: Removed the pipe `|` and change `echo` to `print`  and you are fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general form of an awk command is:

```
awk '<awk script commands>' input-file
```

As `status` is the input file it should follow the awk scripting. The pipe symbol does not make sense here.

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '{
   print $0
}' /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status
```

Comment: oh, sorry for the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: We all make mistakes - it's no problem.